# Ways of Sorting an Array Unity C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, unity-game-engine

Hi basically I have an inventory in a Struct: Inventory Slot[] slots. What I want to do is sort the array
depending on the type of inventory. I don't want to convert it into a List since practically all my code is array based and everything is attached and works well. I tried many ways of going at it looked at all the youtube videos of sorting inventory.

One of the best ways I created :

I tried creating a secondary Array :

```
private void Awake()
        {
           slots = new InventorySlot[inventorySize];
           slotList = new InventorySlot[inventorySize];
        }

public void SortByTypeNameAscending()
        {
            var SortedSlots = slotList.Where(t => t.item != null).OrderBy(t => t.item.GetAllowedEquipLocation()).ToArray();

            slots = SortedSlots;
            inventoryUpdated?.Invoke();
        }
```

When I add an item to inventory or remove it, I update both Arrays doing : slotList = slots in the add or remove function. SlotList holds all the items and Slots will change according to the "Filter". If I remove the Where(t => t.item != null), the problem with that is that if I have slots that are null, well it gives me a null error. Tried doing something like InventorySlot?[] slots and slots = new InventorySlot?[inventorySize] for it to accept nulls but than my sorting function has multiple errors. On the other hand when I use Where(t => t.item != null) if I have 10 slots and 1/10 is null, the sorting works but the inventory becomes an inventory of 9 slots instead of 10 slots(with 1 free slot) and I won't be able to add 1 other Item.

I don't know if there's a way around it, maybe a way to convert it to a List in the function it self and reconvert it to an array? Any Ideas?

Comment: You can use a List to sort, then add the missing pieces to the list and finally converting back the list to an array. (Of course this is feasible if the size of those arrays is not big)

Comment: `var SortedSlots = slotList.OrderBy(t => t?.item?.GetAllowedEquipLocation()).ThenBy(z => z == null).ToArray();` Does this do what you want?

Comment: @Steve I can't use that, the inventory will expand further and further. Down the line it will cause a problem.

Comment: @mjwills If I do that, i get an error on t?. If I delete the ?, I get an error on z ==null....

Comment: " I don't want to convert it into a List" - Lists are actually backed by arrays....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an inventory, I really suggest a `List<InventorySlot>`. You can then remove and insert into the list without having to worry about making a new array or shifting items around.

If you are mapping the inventory to some sort of grid, then I suggest you add an x and y property to the `InventorySlot` class so you can keep track of where it is in the inventory grid. There is no need to keep the list sorted to match the display of the inventory.

This would also make it so you don't need to store two lists of `InventorySlot` items, you can just get by with the one list. When you go to render your inventory grid, simply iterate the list and draw/move the sprite of the item to the right spot.

I realize you have setup code to work with arrays everywhere, but the fact that you have other parts of your game knowing that your inventory is an array is an architecture problem. You should be abstracting your inventory away into some sort of interface that anyone who wants to work with inventory must go through. The internals of how the inventory is stored in memory should not be exposed.

Comment: "but the fact that you have other parts of your game knowing that your inventory is an array is an architecture problem." +1

Comment: @jjxtra Thanks for the answer. Since my InventorySlot was a struct containing item and number,  with an array i would normally do slot[i].item = X. With a List what would be the equivalent of slot[i].item ? or at least how do i get the elements of the struct with a List?

Comment: list.FirsOrDefault(l=>l.Index == x)